# Using <include> in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a **RelativeLayout** with one child as `<include another.xml>`

like this **`root.xml`**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal">
<include layout="@layout/another.xml"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My question is does **Android** honour the `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` at the 
top level of my **`another.xml`**?

My **`another.xml`** is like this:

```
<RelativelLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/control_panel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Basically, I want all the views in my **`another.xml`** to be right aligned to my root.
I have tried above, but the views in my **`another.xml`** is left aligned to my root.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You have to do something like this and Orientation is for LinearLayout only

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <RelativelLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >
    <include layout="@layout/another.xml" />
    </RelativelLayout>

</RelativeLayout><RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```